# Linux command line printf tool that allows the same parameter to be used at many places

Tags: linux, command-line, output, string-formatting, utility

As we can see from this Q&A, [What does {0} mean when found in a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530539/what-does-0-mean-when-found-in-a-string-in-c), C# uses a different approach than C/C++'s printf for String.Format, or Console.WriteLine, which allows the same parameter to be used at many places. E.g.,

```
String.Format("Fib: {0}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0}", 1,  1+1, 1+2)
```

Is there any Linux command line printf tool that has the same benefit of allowing the same parameter to be used at many places?

Comment: You can do this in any shell script; the arguments to the script are named $1, $2, etc, and can each be referred to multiple times.

Comment: No there's no such tool commonly used, but it shouldn't be hard to create (a very simple) one: Just replace the number with the correct argument (can even be done as a simple shell-script). Allowing more complicated formats (precision and such) will be a little harder, but still very possible.

Comment: In addition to what @ErnestFriedman-Hill said, you can even do that in a shell function (don't necessarily need a script).

Comment: No standard way, so just use a function or more parameters.
You do not want somebody asking on StackOverflow `what is this code doing?` keep it readible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one liner, using python (it's easy to write one using other languages).

```
% alias myprintf='python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1].format(*sys.argv[2:])"'
% myprintf "a {0} is a {0} is a {1}" dog cat
a dog is a dog is a cat
```

In the `alias` command, I'm assuming you're using `bash`.

Comment: Super cool! I realize that I can use shell function after asking the question and was ready to use it if no such too exist.