# Adding button click event to reponse.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know if I could add a button click event after `response.redirect()`.

```
protected void lnkEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton lnkEdit = (LinkButton)sender;
     string sno = lnkEdit.CommandArgument;
     Response.Redirect(string.Format("HomePage.aspx?eid={0}", sno));
}
```

this is my code. I want to redirect to a page which comes after clicking a button present in `HomePage.aspx` page without changing the url.

Comment: what is the problem? use `if else` ,if you want to redirect on some condition basis

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not exactly clear.

If you want to redirect to other page without changing the url you can use:

```
Server.Transfer(string.Format("HomePage.aspx?eid={0}", sno));
```

Here is [server transfer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You can't add button click event after system `Redirect`. The execution of current page will be terminated after `Redirect`. If you want to execute something after redirecting, you can redirect to page with specific query param and on loading of the redirected page, execute wanted logic if the param is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
        string sno = lnkEdit.CommandArgument;
        if(sender)
        Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx?eid=" + sno);
}
```

Comment: The {0} was the mistake

Comment: [See Meaning of {0}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530539/what-does-0-mean-when-found-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Sure, but I'm not using string formatting now, am I ?

Comment: Simple Answer : Your answer doesn't make any difference to OP question. Both works exactly similar.