# What does {0} mean when found in a key-value pair in C# config file?

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I have run into the use of {0} in the App.config of a project I'm working on and I can't find anything on how it works. The only other question on it I found is the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530539/what-does-0-mean-when-found-in-a-string-in-c) which explains how [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) works but nothing about its use in the .config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="UriUpdateProfile" value="{0}/profiles/{1}" />
      ...
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Please include the C# code that reads the `UriUpdateProfile` entry from config. I'd bet my money that you are running `string.Format` on it.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it but now that I've done more research I'm willing to bet the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hard-coded strings that depend on user data, these sorts of configurations play very well with format strings.  Your example configuration would be read and updated with

```
String.Format(uriUpdateProfile, variable0, variable1);
```

String.Format takes a large number of variables and repacles `{0}` and `{1}` with the passed in arguments.  There are other ways to replicate this, and even simple replacements such as `String.Replace("{0}", userID);` could suffice.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean anything in the config file. In the code, this literal string `"{0}/profiles/{1}"` will be acquired from the configuration. This string will then be used in a composite formatting function such as `String.Format` or `Console.WriteLine`. In the code, where those functions are called, you'll find the arguments that fill in the `"{0}"` and `"{1}"` placeholders.